# My stored procedure doesn't returns rows, but my view does

Tags: sql-server

I've designed the following view and tried to use it as a stored procedure; however, my stored procedure does not return the same rows as my view.

My view returns 46 rows:

```
SELECT   
   NDC_Text, Trade_Name, Vendor_Code, SUM(Quantity_Received) AS QTY, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7070 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7070], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7071 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7071], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7700 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7700], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7701 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7701], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7702 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7702], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7703 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7703], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7703 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7705],
   SUM(Cost_Center_Dollars) AS Total, Program_Type
FROM  dbo.VDP_Master_Drug_Receipts_Log 
WHERE Date_Entered BETWEEN '10/1/2011' AND '11/1/2011'
   AND (Program_Type = 'VDP-BULK')
GROUP BY NDC_Text, Trade_Name, Vendor_Code, Program_Type
ORDER BY Trade_Name
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WicF2.gif)

My stored procedure

```
GO ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShowProductByCategory](@StartDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime, @Type Varchar(15))
AS
Return 
SELECT NDC_Text, Trade_Name, Vendor_Code, SUM(Quantity_Received) AS QTY, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7070 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7070], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7071 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7071], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7700 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7700], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7701 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7701], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7702 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7702], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7703 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7703], 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7703 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7705],
   SUM(Cost_Center_Dollars) AS Total, Program_Type
FROM dbo.VDP_Master_Drug_Receipts_Log 
WHERE Date_Entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StartDate
   AND (Program_Type = 'Type')
GROUP BY NDC_Text, Trade_Name, Vendor_Code, Program_Type
ORDER BY Trade_Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stored procedure is **selecting a dataset** - so you don't need (and must not have) a `RETURN` clause in there!

Try this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShowProductByCategory]
    (@StartDate DateTime, @EndDate DateTime, @Type Varchar(15))
AS
  -- Return    NO RETURN HERE !!
    SELECT 
       NDC_Text, Trade_Name, Vendor_Code, SUM(Quantity_Received) AS QTY, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7070 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7070], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7071 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7071], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7700 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7700], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7701 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7701], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7702 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7702], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7703 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7703], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Cost_Center = 7703 THEN Cost_Center_Dollars ELSE 0 END) AS [7705],
       SUM(Cost_Center_Dollars) AS Total, Program_Type
    FROM dbo.VDP_Master_Drug_Receipts_Log 
    WHERE Date_Entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND (Program_Type = 'Type')
    GROUP BY 
        NDC_Text, Trade_Name, Vendor_Code, Program_Type
    ORDER BY 
        Trade_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure's `WHERE` clause has

```
WHERE Date_Entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StartDate
```

That should probably be `@EndDate`

There is also a different `Progam_Type`, which would lead to different results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in WHERE clause

```
WHERE Date_Entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StartDate
   AND (Program_Type = 'Type')
```

I think it must be

```
WHERE Date_Entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
   AND (Program_Type = @Type)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've changed my code in the stored procedure to "WHERE Date_Entered BETWEEN "@StartDate" AND "@EndDate" AND (Program_Type = "@Type")
GROUP BY NDC_Text, Trade_Name, Vendor_Code, Program_Type
ORDER BY Trade_Name"  But it's still returning a value of 0 as an INT field in SQL SSMS.  Can it be the "RETURN" in the store procedure.

Comment: @JavonFisher this comment would probably be a good thing to update your question with so it gets more exposure (and the query change will be easier to read)

Comment: @JavonFisher Of course, I didn't notice RETURN. As marc_s said you need to delete it.

Comment: @Mark That worked!!!  I've removed the return and it worked.  I'm so used to VB.net function methods that use the return feature.  Thanks

Comment: @Igor Thanks for your assistance.  I need to examine my code more closely in the future.